# fpassthru() alternative

Tags: php, wordpress, minify

I'm using [WP-MINIFY](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-minify/) plugin on my Wordpress blog but because of my server's security configurations, [fpassthru()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) function is disable. So, i have to find an alternative way, so i can edit plugin.

I'm getting this error on minified files :

**Warning**:  fpassthru() has been disabled for security reasons in **/home/blablabla/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min/lib/Minify/Cache/File.php** on line **84**

This is the function which using fpassthru :

```
/**
 * Send the cached content to output
 *
 * @param string $id cache id (e.g. a filename)
 */
public function display($id)
{
    if ($this->_locking) {
        $fp = fopen($this->_path . '/' . $id, 'rb');
        flock($fp, LOCK_SH);
        fpassthru($fp);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        readfile($this->_path . '/' . $id);            
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm very confused as to why a provider would disable `fpassthru`. It's nothing more but a file read, and as the answers show pretty easy to replace. It's quite likely that this is blocked in error and **[`passthru`](http://php.net/passthru)** was meant to be (because that's an exec command). You should open a ticket with your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
public function display($id)
{
    $filename=$this->_path . '/' . $id;
    if ($this->_locking) {
        $fp = fopen($filename, 'rb');
        flock($fp, LOCK_SH);
        //fpassthru($fp);
        $out=fread($fp,filesize($filename));
        echo $out;
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        readfile($filename);            
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not similar with file processing with php. I will remove `fpassthru()`'s line and then add this line, instead of `fpassthru()` right?

Comment: See my updated answer, with a complete version of the new function.

Comment: thank you. THis method more optimized when we compare with @phihag's answer?

Comment: @Eray No, this will be (if only very slightly) slower because an additional system call is needed to determine the file's size. With either solution the whole file will be read to memory before any output is started. Also, this version would fail if another process appends to the file without bothering to lock it between the calls to `filesize` and `fread`. (but that's a very far-fetched scenario). In that case, you would only read a part of the file.

Comment: So, which method you advice me?

Comment: @Eray Since `fread($fp, filesize())` will be in-perceivably slower in the best cases and about 2* slower in the worst and needlessly introduces from the above-mentioned bugs, I'd go with `stream_get_contents` as described in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo stream_get_contents($fp);
```

(instead of the `fpassthru` line) does the same thing, only with more memory consumption (and less optimized than `fpassthru`).